# WordPress add_filter( 'body_class' ) in __construct not working

Tags: wordpress, class, construct, add-filter

It maybe that the filter is firing too late for this to work, but this is what I have, and it isn't working.

```
class someClass()
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'body_class', array( 'someClass', 'body_class_filter') );
    }

    public function body_class_filter( $classes )
    {
        $classes[] = 'some-class';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

I have also tried

```
add_filter( 'body_class', array( $this, 'body_class_filter') );
```

or

```
add_filter( 'body_class', array( &$this, 'body_class_filter') );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'body_class', array( __CLASS__, 'body_class_filter') );
```

But that filter does not appear to be firing.  I've even put in a trigger_warning() in the function body_class_filter() to see if the code is even processing and it doesn't appear to be since no warning is showing up in the debug.log.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you instantiating the class? Add `new someClass();` at the bottom of your file. My suggestion would be to go with the following version of `add_filter()`:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', array( $this, 'body_class_filter' ) );
```

Finally, if you are instantiating the class, are you doing so before the `body_class` filter is run?

Comment: yes the class is being instantiated, it is being instantiated when the page-template is called, which most likely, I would guess, done after the body class filter has run. Which is all I can imagine being the issue at this point.